# How to fetch the single record of each user in sql record

Tags: sql-server

I have to fetch a single record of each user which is the last entry in the table. The table has multiple records of each user.

```
select userid, UserNM, UserPMobileNo
into #user
from tbUserMaster
where UserStatus = 1


select a.userid, a.UserNM, a.UserPMobileNo, SUM(b.uAmount) as [load]
into #bal
from #user a
  left join tbbalance b on a.UserID = b.UserID and b.uAmount = ABS(b.uAmount)
group by a.UserID, a.UserNM, a.UserPMobileNo


select distinct u.*, sum(b.pTotalAmt ) as [Net Usage]
into #Sale1
from #bal u
  left join tbProcTransactions b on u.UserID = b.pUserID
    and (b.pMessContent not like '%Failure%' or b.pMessContent != 'Failed')
group by u.userid, u.UserNM, u.UserPMobileNo, u.[load], b.pCurrentBalance, b.pTotalAmt


select a.userid, a.UserNM, a.UserPMobileNo, a.[load], (pCurrentBalance + pTotalAmt) as [OB]
into #OB
from tbProcTransactions b
  inner join #bal a on b.pUserID=a.userid
```

Here I am getting the final result I want to fetch total amount of each user.

```
select a.userid, a.UserNM, a.UserPMobileNo, a.[load], (pCurrentBalance + pTotalAmt) as [OB]
into #OB
from tbProcTransactions b
  inner join #bal a on b.pUserID = a.userid
```

But I am getting 100000 records but actual record is 4000.

How can I get a single record for each user?

Comment: SELECT ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY YourColumn) as RowNumber

Comment: When you say "last entry in the table", which table is this? how do you know this specifically?

Comment: @DavidR Last entry means the latest entry of a user

Comment: Got it, you want only the record with the maximum datetime in [tbProcTransactions].

Comment: @DavidR yes u r right

Answer (score 0):

Table named [tbProcTransactions] has multiple record per UserID. When you join #bal to [tbProcTransactions], every record in #bal matches multiple records in [tbProcTransactions] which causes extra rows to be returned.

In order to limit the number of rows, you must specify additional criteria in your WHERE statement. For example:

```
select a.userid, a.UserNM, a.UserPMobileNo, a.[load], (pCurrentBalance + pTotalAmt) as [OB]
into #OB
from tbProcTransactions b
  inner join #bal a on b.pUserID = a.userid

-- added code, using a timestamp field.
-- If there is a possibility of one user having multiple entries on the same timestamp, you will need to also sort by an auto-numbered field.
-- TODO: change this to the correct DATETIME field name
WHERE b.timestampfield=(
    SELECT MAX(c.timestampfield)
    FROM tbProcTransactions c
    WHERE c.userid=a.userid
)
```

Comment: and what if i want record base on datetime. what date i select then how can i do it?

Comment: Revised answer to only select the [tbProcTransactions] record with the MAX(timestamp) for each user, causing one row to be returned from this table.